# PHP curl return curl_errno 3

Tags: php, php-curl

Here is my php code , when I run it. It return me error_no is 3.
 I can not figure it out what happened.

```
 $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($param));            
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        //echo http_build_query($param);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $errorCode = curl_errno($curl);
```

Comment: Your URL is malformed. See [curl error codes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php#103128). Show us your `$url` value.

Comment: Please have full curl code over here! missing curl url $param ? $timeout ?

Answer (score 3):

error_no 3 is CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT, so check if the url you're using is correct http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php#103128